# How to measure FPS in Android?

Tags: android, frame-rate

I'm looking for a piece of code that could measure FPS everywhere, not just in games, but in other apps or even in the home screen. I want to be able to log FPS frequently, i.e. every second.

I know there are some apps that measure FPS in games. I have also tried FPS Meter and it seems to be very inaccurate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533511/doing-an-android-fps-counter

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I'm one of the senior engineers at GameBench.

You can use GameBench to measure FPS information on the UI, apps, and games for iOS and Android. We have an Android only app and a cross-platform desktop profiler - both of these also include CPU/GPU/memory and network info.

We guarantee its accuracy as well, and work closely with hardware and software partners like Samsung, Nvidia, and Qualcomm.

[GameBench site](https://www.gamebench.net)

[Playstore link to app](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gamebench.metricscollector)

Comment: I have used GameBench and it is a very nice tool. See my experience with GameBench tool at http://stackoverflow.com/a/41951555/1811356 (How to measure FPS on Android during app development)

Comment: Note to others re. GameBench. They offer a trial version, but you cannot download it. You must give away your non-gmail address, the company you work for, a telephone number, your full name, and your location. You must then wait for a 'specialist' to contact you... a real shame.